# The continuity of the rational maps in the zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How can one show that the a rational map $f:V\rightarrow W$ is Zariski-continuous? ($V$ and $W$ are affine varieties, i.e. irreducible closed algebraic sets.)

Comment: Assaf, i see you're new here, so: did you know you can "accept" an answer by clicking the check mark next to it? :) This shows that you are happy with the answer..

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to use the term "regular function" or "morphism of varieties" instead of "rational map". (To the future readers of this question.)

Answer (score 4):

Since a rational map $V\dashrightarrow W$ is technically not a map $V\to W$, I hope it suffices to show that for some open $U\subseteq V$ where $f$ is defined, $f_U:U\to W$ is continuous. For that, it will suffice to show that morphisms of algebraic varieties are continuous. Well then, let $Z\subseteq W$ be closed. Let $f:U\to W$ be a morphism of algebraic varieties and let $\phi:k[W]\to k[U]$ be the corresponding morphism of coordinate rings, i.e. $\phi(a)= a\circ f$. Note that, if $p\in U$ corresponds to the maximal ideal $I(p)$, then $f(p)$ corresponds to the maximal ideal $\phi^{-1}(I(p))$.
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(Z) &= \{ p\in U\mid f(p)\in Z \} \\
 &= \{p\in U\mid I(Z) \subseteq I(f(p)) = \phi^{-1}(I(p)) \} \\
 &= \{p\in U\mid \phi(I(Z)) \subseteq  I(p) \} \\
 &= Z(\phi(I(Z))).
\end{align*}
Hence, the preimage of a closed set is closed.